# Forward/Backward fill na by incrementing/decrementing last found value?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following pandas data frame *(a copy of it can by found [here](http://pastebin.com/5VRPDqCZ))*. How to fill na in a separate column with incrementing/decrementing nr of rows until the next signal value and the forward/backward signal value? 
The signal value is only: 1; -1 or np.na

```
+----+---------+--------+
|    | Values  | Signal |
+----+---------+--------+
|  0 | 1420.49 |        |
|  1 | 1421.12 |        |
|  2 | 1418.95 |        |
|  3 | 1419.04 |      1 |
|  4 | 1419.04 |        |
|  5 | 1417.51 |        |
|  6 | 1416.97 |        |
|  7 | 1413.21 |     -1 |
|  8 | 1411.49 |        |
|  9 | 1412.57 |        |
| 10 | 1408.55 |      1 |
| 11 | 1409.16 |        |
| 12 | 1413.38 |        |
| 13 | 1413.38 |      1 |
| 14 | 1402.35 |        |
| 15 |  1397.8 |        |
| 16 | 1398.36 |        |
| 17 | 1397.62 |        |
| 18 | 1394.58 |     -1 |
| 19 | 1399.05 |        |
| 20 |  1399.9 |        |
| 21 | 1398.96 |     -1 |
| 22 | 1398.96 |        |
| 23 | 1393.69 |        |
| 24 | 1398.13 |        |
| 25 | 1398.66 |        |
| 26 | 1398.02 |      1 |
| 27 | 1397.97 |        |
| 28 | 1396.05 |        |
| 29 | 1398.13 |        |
+----+---------+--------+
```

The result should be something like this in the end ([here](http://pastebin.com/uCvwXk77) is a copy of it):

```
+----+---------+--------+------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|    | Values  | Signal | forward signal rows nr | backward signal rows | value at signal |
+----+---------+--------+------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|  0 | 1420.49 |        |                        |                      |                 |
|  1 | 1421.12 |        |                        |                      |                 |
|  2 | 1418.95 |        |                        |                      |                 |
|  3 | 1419.04 |      1 |                      1 |                    4 |         1416.97 |
|  4 | 1419.04 |        |                      2 |                    3 |         1416.97 |
|  5 | 1417.51 |        |                      3 |                    2 |         1416.97 |
|  6 | 1416.97 |        |                      4 |                    1 |         1416.97 |
|  7 | 1413.21 |     -1 |                     -1 |                   -3 |         1412.57 |
|  8 | 1411.49 |        |                     -2 |                   -2 |         1412.57 |
|  9 | 1412.57 |        |                     -3 |                   -1 |         1412.57 |
| 10 | 1408.55 |      1 |                      1 |                    3 |         1413.38 |
| 11 | 1409.16 |        |                      2 |                    2 |         1413.38 |
| 12 | 1413.38 |        |                      3 |                    1 |         1413.38 |
| 13 | 1413.38 |      1 |                      1 |                    5 |         1397.62 |
| 14 | 1402.35 |        |                      2 |                    4 |         1397.62 |
| 15 |  1397.8 |        |                      3 |                    3 |         1397.62 |
| 16 | 1398.36 |        |                      4 |                    2 |         1397.62 |
| 17 | 1397.62 |        |                      5 |                    1 |         1397.62 |
| 18 | 1394.58 |     -1 |                     -1 |                   -3 |          1399.9 |
| 19 | 1399.05 |        |                     -2 |                   -2 |          1399.9 |
| 20 |  1399.9 |        |                     -3 |                   -1 |          1399.9 |
| 21 | 1398.96 |     -1 |                     -1 |                   -5 |         1398.66 |
| 22 | 1398.96 |        |                     -2 |                   -4 |         1398.66 |
| 23 | 1393.69 |        |                     -3 |                   -3 |         1398.66 |
| 24 | 1398.13 |        |                     -4 |                   -2 |         1398.66 |
| 25 | 1398.66 |        |                     -5 |                   -1 |         1398.66 |
| 26 | 1398.02 |      1 |                      1 |                    4 |         1398.13 |
| 27 | 1397.97 |        |                      2 |                    3 |         1398.13 |
| 28 | 1396.05 |        |                      3 |                    2 |         1398.13 |
| 29 | 1398.13 |        |                      4 |                    1 |         1398.13 |
+----+---------+--------+------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
```

I achieved the final result with a few nested loops but the problem is that they are very inefficient on larger data frames of a few million rows.

Comment: .. did you just remove a column and change the definition of backward signal rows?

Comment: yes, i am sorry for that, realized that it was the wrong result i was asking for. but if you already have a solution for that, you can just post it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual approach to signal-based groupings (which we should really have better native support for, IMHO) to use the compare-cumsum-groupby pattern.  Here the comparison is to determine whether a signal entry is null or not, after which we do a cumulative sum so that each signal group has its own id (group id, or gid).  The rest is just arithmetic.

While there's some duplication here we could refactor away, I'm feeling lazy, and so:

```
gid = df["Signal"].notnull().cumsum()
dg = df.groupby(gid)
sign = dg["Signal"].transform("first")
df["forward signal rows"] = (dg.cumcount() + 1) * sign
df["backward signal rows"] = (dg["Signal"].transform("size") - dg.cumcount()) * sign
df["value at signal"] = dg["Values"].transform("last")
df.loc[gid == 0, "value at signal"] = np.nan
```

gives me a frame matching your target one.

Comment: Thank you @DSM :) it's a really nice approach :)