# python: specify window around observation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 id     indicator  
  1         NaN 
  1         NaN
  1         1
  1         NaN 
  1         NaN
  1         NaN
  1         1
  1         NaN
  1         NaN
  1         NaN
```

In reality I have several ids. I now want to forward fill the indicator column for the next 2 columns, but with the extra that the forward fill increases by 1 every step. The result should look like this:

```
 id     indicator  
  1         NaN  
  1         NaN
  1         1
  1         2 
  1         3
  1         NaN
  1         1
  1         2 
  1         3
  1         NaN
```

I know the command:

```
df.groupby("id")["indicator"].fillna(value=None, method="ffill", limit=3)
```

This command works fine, but I do not know how to make it increase by 1 every step instead of just carry forwarding the old value. Can anybody help?

Edit: 
I tried something like this but get invalid syntax. Can I shift a where command?

```
 for i in range(1,20):
      df["indicator"].where(df["indicator"])==1).shift(+i) = i
```

This is not an duplicate to [Forward/Backward fill na by incrementing/decrementing last found value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748028/forward-backward-fill-na-by-incrementing-decrementing-last-found-value) , because there there is no limit in the incremention. Here, I basically want to have a window +-2 marked whenever the indicator is 1.

Comment: What is the exact output you need ?

Comment: Whenever the value of indicator is 1, I want the next value to be 2 and the next after that to be 3. Notice that I have several values of 1 in the column. The desired result is given in the op.

Comment: Try this `df_fill = df.groupby('id')['indicator'].ffill(limit=2)` then
`df_fill.groupby(by=df_fill.ne(1).cumsum()).cumcount().replace(0,np.nan)`

Comment: Looks good, but I get "invalid character in identifier". Maybe the ne(1) is wrong?

Comment: Friedrich, if you copied the text from this comment and didn't check it, there are some invalid characters when you paste that text into your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby`, `ffill`, `cumsum`, and `cumcount`:

```
print(df)

   id  indicator
0   1        NaN
1   1        NaN
2   1        1.0
3   1        NaN
4   1        NaN
5   1        NaN
6   1        1.0
7   1        NaN
8   1        NaN
9   1        NaN


df_fill = df.groupby('id')['indicator'].ffill(limit=2) 
df_fill.groupby(by=df_fill.ne(1).cumsum()).cumcount().replace(0,np.nan)
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    3.0
5    NaN
6    1.0
7    2.0
8    3.0
9    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfect. I had to add sort=False to the groupby command though. But I guess that has more to do with my df then this example.