# pandas increment cell value by 0.1

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks similar to below:

```
    A
0   1
1   NaN
2   2
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   3
6   4
8   NaN
9   5
10  NaN
```

What I want it is:

```
    A
0   1
1   1.1
2   2
3   2.1
4   2.2
5   3
6   4
8   4.1
9   5
10  5.1
```

The missing values I want to fill incrementally by 0.1. I have been playing with np.arrange but I cannot work out how to piece everything together. I feel I am on the right path but would appreciate some help. thank you

```
In []: import pandas as pd
In []: import numpy as np

In []: np.arange(1, 2, 0.1)
Out[]: array([1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9])

In []: def up(x):                                                                     
           return x.astype(str) + '.' + np.arange(len(x)).astype(str)

In []: data = pd.DataFrame([[1,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,1]], columns=["A", "B"])

In []: out = data.apply(up).values
array([['1.0', '0.0'],
       ['0.1', '1.1'],
       ['1.2', '0.2'],
       ['0.3', '1.3']], dtype=object)

In []: df = pd.DataFrame(out)
     A    B
  0  1.0  0.0
  1  0.1  1.1
  2  1.2  0.2
  3  0.3  1.3
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the first columns is NaN?

Comment: Related: [Forward/Backward fill na by incrementing/decrementing last found value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748028/forward-backward-fill-na-by-incrementing-decrementing-last-found-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit hard to get that point

```
s=df.A.isnull().astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum()[df.A.isnull()]# creat the group Id for those NaN value , if they are NaN they belong to same Id

df.A.fillna(df.A.ffill()+s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).mul(0.1))# then we using fillna , and creat the position inorder to adding the .01 for each

Out[1764]: 
0     1.0
1     1.1
2     2.0
3     2.1
4     2.2
5     3.0
6     4.0
8     4.1
9     5.0
10    5.1
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: You can get almost desired results using `df.fillna(df.shift(1) + .1)`, but it won't fill more than one NaN in a row.  Is there a way to use the intermediate results to accomplish this?

Comment: I tried shift and it worked nicely to begin with. The problem I have is this is part of a much larger data frame and I do not always know how many increments I am going to need. I guess I could set a column to count them and use that in some way. The above code posted by Wen seems to work nicely. Ill have a play with it and let you know. thank you for the help..

Comment: This resolves my problem nicely. I have accepted this as the answer but cannot up vote it as I do not have enough reputation.. thanks again..